# "Sys is not defined" error when adding custom validation (MVC Foolproof validation)

Tags: javascript, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, foolproof-validation

I'm trying to add a custom validator using the MVC Foolproof library.

However, upon following the instructions [here](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/client-side-model-aware-validation/) I get the error message "Sys is not defined".

I suspect this is because the library was originally written to work with the older validation script files which came with MVC 2 (and possibly 3), so is there a way to register my validation function for the javascript validation files which come with MVC 4?

The property on my model is defined as

```
[RatingTextRequired(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ModelResources.Customer.Order.FeedbackRating), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredError_Comment")]
public string FeedbackText { get; set; }
```

The validation attribute is defined as

```
public class RatingTextRequiredAttribute : ModelAwareValidationAttribute
{
    //this is needed to register this attribute with foolproof's validator adapter
    static RatingTextRequiredAttribute()
    {
        Register.Attribute(typeof (RatingTextRequiredAttribute));
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value, object container)
    {
        var model = (Areas.Customer.Models.FeedbackRating) container;

        return !(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()) && (model.WantsPostEditing || model.Rating == "0"));
    }
}
```

And the JavaScript wiring-up for this is

```
Sys.Mvc.ValidatorRegistry.validators["ratingtextrequired"] = function (rule) {

    return function(value, context) {

        var wantsPostEditingProp = foolproof.getId(context.fieldContext.elements[0], "WantsPostEditing");
        var wantsPostEditingVal = document.getElementById(wantsPostEditingProp).value;

        var ratingProp = foolproof.getId(context.fieldContext.elements[0], "Rating");
        var ratingVal = document.getElementById(ratingProp).value;

        return !(value.length == 0 && (wantsPostEditingVal || ratingVal === "0"));
    };
};
```

Also, I'm not sure what the file MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.js is requied for because somehow I had the out-of-the-box validation working without this script file being present. Sadly, including it doesn't help with my "Sys is not defined" error.

Comment: I use foolproof in mvc 4 with no issues.  Can you add the code that is throwing the error?  and your model,  how you are defining the required

Comment: I've updated the question with all relevant code/javascript.

Comment: possible duplicated of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541452

Answer (score 0):

Base on your error you are using the jquery obstructive approach.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644838/how-to-make-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-work-with-foolproofs-modelawarev/21814158#21814158) for more info.